# How to find the Iframe content scrollheight and scroll width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to this Jquery and i have a trouble to find the iframe scrollheight and scrollwidth when the iframe hosting the external webpage.
i tried following code but its doesn't work and i searched a lot.

```
$.fn.hasVerticalScrollbar = function () {
    // This will return true, when the div has vertical scrollbar
    return $frame[0].document.documentElement.offsetHeight() > this.height();
  }
  $.fn.hasHorizontalScrollbar = function () {
    // This will return true, when the div has horizontal scrollbar
    return $frame[0].document.documentElement.offsetWidth() > this.width();
}
```

help please.

Comment: Are you trying to access content inside the iFrame?

Comment: i need to find whether iframe has scrollbar or not.. not access the content..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code... it will help you.... it works perfectly for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function Sam()
{
var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
var hasHorizontalScroll= iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth>iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.clientWidth;
var hasVerticalScroll= iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight>iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight;

alert(" Horiz : " + hasHorizontalScroll);
alert(" Verti : " + hasVerticalScroll);
}
</script>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" id="idIframe">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<input type="button" value="find" onclick="Sam();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem, and I am not sure if the code you have provided will work if the page is hosted somewhere else.